# What is the best way to profile a view in Django?

Tags: python, django, optimization, profiling

I have developed an application using Django and everything is working fine but I don't know what's going on behind the scenes. I would like to know:

- How many times the database is being hit for each request?
- What was the execution time for each query?
- How long it took to render the template?
- Regular profiling info (ncalls, tottime per function).

Is there a Middleware to handle this that I could install? Which are the best practices to profile my views?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

three words: [Django Debug Toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar)

Answer (score 2):

The one project that meets all your requirements, with the exception of profiling, is the excellent [django debug toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar).

For standard profiling you need to use [repoze.profile](http://svn.repoze.org/repoze.profile/trunk/) (which means you have to be running Django with WSGI interface such as mod_wsgi).

If you're hardcore and need to debug memory leaks use [dozer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Dozer/0.1) (also a WSGI component).

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if debug %}
    <div id="debug">
    <h2>Queries</h2>
    <p>
        {{ sql_queries|length }} Quer{{ sql_queries|pluralize:"y,ies" }}
        {% ifnotequal sql_queries|length 0 %}
        (<span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="var s=document.getElementById('debugQueryTable').style;s.display=s.display=='none'?'':'none';this.innerHTML=this.innerHTML=='Show'?'Hide':'Show';">Show</span>)
        {% endifnotequal %}
    </p>
    <table id="debugQueryTable" style="display: none;">
        <col width="1"></col>
        <col></col>
        <col width="1"></col>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">SQL</th>
        <th scope="col">Time</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for query in sql_queries %}<tr class="{% cycle odd,even %}">
        <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td>{{ query.sql|escape }}</td>
        <td>{{ query.time }}</td>
        </tr>{% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

[Django Snippet: Template Query Debug](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/93/)

Answer (score 0):

For people arriving in 2019+, `django-debug-toolbar` is still great, but just as a heads-up, most of the template profiling panes are broken in modern Django versions (2.0+).

Another good option these days is [`django-silk`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk) which has some beautiful timing profile visualization and graphing features, and [`django-live-profiler`](https://github.com/InviteBox/django-live-profiler) with a working [fork for Django v2.0+ here](https://github.com/pirate/django-live-profiler).

[image][image]